# C array, moving elements to the right not working as expected

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

Im attempting to shift the position of every element in an array to the right by 1 to insert a new object and its not working as expected, what is wrong with this code?
edit: it replaces the first element with the new obj and drops the last element when inserting something that would go to the first index of the array. The array has a capacity for 1020 objects, there are currently 14 in the array

```
for(i = 0; i < *size; i++){
      if((obj.ID < array[i].ID) || (obj.ID < array[i].ID)){
        size_t j;
        for(j = *size-1; j > i-1; j--){
          array[j] = array[j-1];//array[j+1] = array[j];
        }
        array[i] = obj.ID;
        *size = *size + 1;
        return array;
      }
    }
```

Comment: You are missing definitions of many of your variables and types... You should at least provide a complete function, and usually an example of how you call it (including definitions of any parameter variables you pass). And then "not working as expected" does not tell neither what you expect, nor what you see.

Comment: Why do you check `(obj.ID < array[i].ID)` twice?

Comment: @Michael Burr  he does this for reliability.:) If by accident the first subexpression will be equal to false then the second subexpression will re-check the result.:)

Comment: haha typo @VladfromMoscow

Comment: @user2038460 The correct approach to your task is 1) to use the binary search 2) to use standard C function memmove to shift elements of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsigned integer wrap-around.

```
for(j = *size-1; j > i-1; j--){
```

`j` is type `size_t` so `j > i-1` is certainly a comparison of 2 unsigned types.  Since `i=0` at first, the comparison is `j > some_very_large_unsigned_value`.

An unchecked solution may be to add 1 to both sides.

```
   for(j = *size-1; j+1 > i; j--){
      array[j] = array[j-1];
    }
    // or simply
   for(j = *size; j-- > i; ){
      array[j] = array[j-1];
    }
```

Also increment size beforehand:

```
    if (*size >= 1020) Handle_TooMany();        
    *size = *size + 1;
    for(j = *size; j-- > i; ){
      array[j] = array[j-1];
    }
```

Comment: your solution worked! only thing i don't understand is the syntax of your second for loop, could you explain it a little?

Comment: also the last element is dropped

Comment: @user2038460 Rather than subtracting 1 in `j = *size-1`, do `j = *size`.  Now `j` is one higher when code gets to the compare.  So code does not need to add 1 as before with `j+1 > i`, as `j > i` will do.  But the body of the `for()` loop needs the decremented value, so we do  `j-- > i`.

Comment: i get what you're saying. the array has enough space for 1020 objects, there are currently 14 objects in the array. it was created like this notation Object objects[1020]

Comment: As @5gon12eder suggested, using `memmove()` is the preferred method to shift memory.  `memmove(&array[1], &array[0], *size * sizeof array[0]);  *size = *size + 1;`.

Comment: I used memmove, once again it worked and its simple.. + i gained a new skill.. i'd accept this and 5gon12eder's answer if i could

Answer (score 0):

first iteration of the outer most loop, when `i = 0`

```
for(j = *size-1; j > i-1; j--)
```

this loop will go from `size - 1` to `i` (`i` value included), so when j becomes 0 in the last iteration, the assigning statement inside looks something like this

```
 array[0] = array[-1];
```

thats where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make much sense to me.  If what you want to do is shift all elements to the right by one, the first thing you should worry about is what should happen to the last element.  Should it be lost?  Should we grow the array?  The latter can only be done if the array was allocated  dynamically using `malloc`.

Let's assume that we are willing to lose the last element (at position `n - 1`) in an array `array` of length `n`.  Here is how we could shift:

```
int i;
for (i = n - 1; i > 0; --i)
  array[i] = array[i - 1];
```

Note that we start at the end of the array and move towards the beginning.  (Can you imagine what would happen otherwise?)

If you want maximum performance, consider using `memmove` instead of your self-rolled loop but starting with doing it manually helps getting better understanding.

**Update:**

> how would you make it so that the last element isn't dropped?.. if possible

The copying is the same, except that the loop starts out with `n` instead of `n - 1`.  However, this can only work if the array is at least of size `n + 1`.  If you know the maximum number of elements ahead of time, you can create a large-enough array up front.  Often times, however, you won't know it and this is when you have to use dynamic memory.

You can allocate a buffer large enough to hold `n` variables of type `int` via

```
int * buffer = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
if (buffer == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: out of memory\n");
    abort();
  }
```

and re-size it to be capable of holding `m` elements later via

```
int * tmp = realloc(buffer, m * sizeof(int));
if (tmp == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: out of memory\n");
    abort();
  }
else
  {
    buffer = tmp;
    /* 'buffer' can now hold 'm' integers. */
  }
```

If you do this, avoid changing the size one-by-one as this is very inefficient.  Instead, keep track of the current *capacity* and the currently *used size* in two separate variables and always adjust the capacity by a factor of 2.

After you don't need the buffer any longer, give it back to the system:

```
free(buffer);
```

I have recently posted [a working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753951/how-to-allocate-memory-in-c-for-each-character-at-a-time-for-double-pointers-cha/25755572#25755572) of managing such a dynamic array as an answer to another question.  Maybe you'll find it useful, too.

Comment: how would you make it so that the last element isn't dropped?.. if possible